# How to take Oracle backup and restore?

Tags: oracle, backup, restore

I am coming from SQL Server background where SQL Server studio has a very easy way of taking database backup and then doing a restore.

I have been using Oracle 11G express edition for past couple of months and I am not sure of doing the backup and restore in oracle.

I can see the option to backup database and restore databse in oracle server menu but I am not sure how does it work, where does it creates the backup file etc.

Please help

Answer (score 8):

rman is the way to go for backup and recovery for protection against physical corruption. For documentation check [Oracle® Database 2 Day DBA
11g Release 2 (11.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/backrest.htm#i1004902)
In the current release of SQLDeveloper backup and recovery is integrated in the GUI. For download of SQLDeveloper see [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) It is a free product, with active development.

In SQLdeveloper in the View menu select DBA to get access to the dba tools like RMAN and DATAPUMP. Very nice tool. Don't forget that the backup files are written by the Oracle database server processes. This means that the backups are written on the database server, not on your client. Also, currently it just generates a backup script. You should run the generated script using RMAN.

An other way to run and configure the backup is by using dbconsole or grid control.

Using datapump is an other way to protect against data loss. Using this enables you to read back the data as it was during the export. Might be usefull for test sets that have to be refreshed with a specific version of the data. Not really usefull if you want to recover production transactions to the last moment before disaster stroke.

Answer (score 0):

User `RMAN`. Refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/toc.htm) article

Or you can make use of `data pump export/import`. Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm#i1006376) article.

Comment: Thanks for the link. isnt there any simpler UI do this instead of writing some commands?

Comment: Updated my answer to include data pump, simple commands to take backup of database

Comment: Highly dangerous advice: data pump and export are not backup and tools. The main reason being, they are not incremental and they lose data (everything since the last time you ran an export). This is because their main purpose is data transfer not recovery.

Comment: Okay then use RMAN, don't think it needed a downvote